I would like to iterate over a list of svg icons in angular using the *ngFor directive
Here is a list of svg icons in an array; I want to iterate through them in the template.
aboutTags = <AboutTags[]>([
    {
      title: "1 year of",
      sub: "Professional Experience",
      icon: `"<svg class="iconsprimary" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path d="M9.669.864 8 0 6.331.864l-1.858.282-.842 1.68-1.337 1.32L2.6 6l-.306 1.854 1.337 1.32.842 1.68 1.858.282L8 12l1.669-.864 1.858-.282.842-1.68 1.337-1.32L13.4 6l.306-1.854-1.337-1.32-.842-1.68zm1.196 1.193.684 1.365 1.086 1.072L12.387 6l.248 1.506-1.086 1.072-.684 1.365-1.51.229L8 10.874l-1.355-.702-1.51-.229-.684-1.365-1.086-1.072L3.614 6l-.25-1.506 1.087-1.072.684-1.365 1.51-.229L8 1.126l1.356.702z"/>
      <path d="M4 11.794V16l4-1 4 1v-4.206l-2.018.306L8 13.126 6.018 12.1z"/>
  </svg>"`
    },
    {
      title: "10+ Projects",
      sub: "Completed",
      icon: `"<svg class="iconsprimary" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path d="M9.669.864 8 0 6.331.864l-1.858.282-.842 1.68-1.337 1.32L2.6 6l-.306 1.854 1.337 1.32.842 1.68 1.858.282L8 12l1.669-.864 1.858-.282.842-1.68 1.337-1.32L13.4 6l.306-1.854-1.337-1.32-.842-1.68zm1.196 1.193.684 1.365 1.086 1.072L12.387 6l.248 1.506-1.086 1.072-.684 1.365-1.51.229L8 10.874l-1.355-.702-1.51-.229-.684-1.365-1.086-1.072L3.614 6l-.25-1.506 1.087-1.072.684-1.365 1.51-.229L8 1.126l1.356.702z"/>
      <path d="M4 11.794V16l4-1 4 1v-4.206l-2.018.306L8 13.126 6.018 12.1z"/>
  </svg>"`
    },
    {
      title: "Developer",
      sub: "Backend & Frontend devt",
      icon: `"<svg class="iconsprimary" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path d="M9.669.864 8 0 6.331.864l-1.858.282-.842 1.68-1.337 1.32L2.6 6l-.306 1.854 1.337 1.32.842 1.68 1.858.282L8 12l1.669-.864 1.858-.282.842-1.68 1.337-1.32L13.4 6l.306-1.854-1.337-1.32-.842-1.68zm1.196 1.193.684 1.365 1.086 1.072L12.387 6l.248 1.506-1.086 1.072-.684 1.365-1.51.229L8 10.874l-1.355-.702-1.51-.229-.684-1.365-1.086-1.072L3.614 6l-.25-1.506 1.087-1.072.684-1.365 1.51-.229L8 1.126l1.356.702z"/>
      <path d="M4 11.794V16l4-1 4 1v-4.206l-2.018.306L8 13.126 6.018 12.1z"/>
  </svg>"`
    },
    {
      title: "Support",
      sub: "Available support 24/7"
    },

  ])

Here is the div I'm trying to iterate them through;
`<div class="flex items-start" *ngFor="let tag of aboutTags">
        <div class="mr-4 border-2 border-accent bg-accent items-center p-1 rounded-sm hover:fill-accent hover:bg-transparent">
            {{tag.icon}}
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col justify-start">
            <span class="font-semibold tracking-wider text-accent">{{tag.title}}</span>
            <span class="text-xs">{{tag.sub}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>`

Other values are displayed but the svg isn't. How can I get it to display? Thanks

You can use sanitizer to sanitize the html and pass it to innerHTML
export class Some component {
     constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}
    ...
    sanitizeHTML(str: string) {
         return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, str);
    }
    ...

Then you can safely use innerHTML to render an html string
<div class="flex items-start" *ngFor="let tag of aboutTags">
        <div class="mr-4 border-2 border-accent bg-accent items-center p-1 rounded-sm hover:fill-accent hover:bg-transparent">
            <span [innerHTML]="sanitizeHTML(tag.icon)"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col justify-start">
            <span class="font-semibold tracking-wider text-accent">{{tag.title}}</span>
            <span class="text-xs">{{tag.sub}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>


Thank you. Although sanitizer.sanitize didn't show the icons, it helped me get another method from DomSanitizer to show the icons. The method I got is bypassSecurityTrustHtml. It looks like this; sanitizeHTML(str: string){
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(str);
}
